# How to create a circular buttons by changing color and and size when selected using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to create a circular buttons and change size, color when selected?

as the below Image one

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the snippets below :

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool _isSelectedLeftButton = true;
  bool _isSelectedRightButton = false;
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Ink(
          height: _isSelectedLeftButton ? 80.0 : 60.0,
          width: _isSelectedLeftButton ? 80.0 : 60.0,
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: _isSelectedLeftButton ? Colors.lightBlue : Colors.grey,
            shape: CircleBorder(),
          ),
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.sim_card),
            color: Colors.white,
            iconSize: _isSelectedLeftButton ? 40.0 : 30.0,
            onPressed: () {
              setState((){
                _isSelectedLeftButton = true;
                _isSelectedRightButton = false;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
        Ink(
          height: _isSelectedRightButton ? 80.0 : 60.0,
          width: _isSelectedRightButton ? 80.0 : 60.0,
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: _isSelectedRightButton ? Colors.lightBlue : Colors.grey,
            shape: CircleBorder(),
          ),
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.sim_card),
            color: Colors.white,
            iconSize: _isSelectedRightButton ? 40.0 : 30.0,
            onPressed: () {
              setState((){
                _isSelectedLeftButton = false;
                _isSelectedRightButton = true;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer it is really good answer but I found what actually what need in the below link 

https://github.com/Eternali/custom_radio

Comment: could you help me for another question but wen can open a chat window,  am glad for that if you could :D

Comment: You can still post your question on the platform so that everyone can give their own opinions and answers :)

Comment: Sure I'll do that, I'll post my other question :)